# Go, encapsulation and perfomance

Tags: performance, go, compiler-optimization

Code I'm exploring:

```
type Stack struct {
    length int
    values []int
}

func (s *Stack) Push(value int) {
    // ...
}

func (s *Stack) Pop() int {
    // ...
}

func (s *Stack) Length() int {
    return s.length
}
```

Methods `Push` and `Pop` change the `length` field in `Stack` struct. And I wanted to hide this field from other files to prevent code like `stack.length = ...` (Manual `length` change). But I was need to have ability to read this field, so I added getter method - `Length`.

And my question is:

Shouldn't `stack.Length()` become slower than `stack.length`, because it is a function call? I have learnt assembler a bit and I know how many operations program should do to call a function. Have I understand right: By adding getter method `stack.Length()` I protected those who use my lib from bad usage but the cost of it - program's performance? This actually concerns not only Go.

Comment: I promise you if there is a difference it is negligible. There may not be one because the compiler may inline some or all calls to this method.

Comment: Do you really think an inlined method call to a static struct field would impact (!) the performance of your application? Do you have any empirical evidence that this is relevant at all?

Comment: @Volker If I wrote so - why are you asking "Do you really think"?. I explained reason I thought so - assembler. Read about `call` command if you don't understand what am I talking about.

Comment: @Don2Quixote Volker didn't mean it that way. Both Peter and Volker are implying the same that the even if there's a perf gain; it's negligible. The compiler does a lot of optimizations and might inline this.

Comment: @shmsr But as you all said, it can reduce performance. Doesn't matter it "negligible" or not. Matter that it can reduce performance as I thought. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it reduces performance. But if uttermost top performance is the **only** goal your implementation should look like this: `type Stack struct {}; func (s *Stack) Push(_ int) {}; func (s *Stack) Pop() int {return 0}; func (s *Stack) Length() int {return 0)` as this is the fastest possible implementation as it will be removed completely by the optimizer. Unfortunately this implementation has sever drawbacks. Everything is always a compromise and some compromises are so dead simple to make because the drawbacks of one side are totally negligible and thats what I tried to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't `stack.Length()` become slower than `stack.length`, because it is a function call?

[Objection!  Assumes facts not in evidence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objection_(United_States_law))

Specifically:

1. *Why do you think it is a function call?*  It *looks like* one, but actual Go compilers will often expand the code in line.
2. *Why do you think a function call is slower than inline code?*  When measuring actual programs on actual computers, sometimes function calls are *faster* than inline code.  It turns out the crucial part is usually whether the instructions being executed, and their operands, are already in the appropriate CPU caches.  Sometimes, expanding functions inline makes the program run more slowly.

The compiler should do the inline expansion unless it makes the program run more slowly.  How good the compiler is at pre- or post-detecting such slowdowns, if present, is a separate issue.  In this particular case, given the function definition, the compiler is almost certain to just expand the function in line, as accessing `stack.length` will likely be one instruction, and calling a function will be one instruction, and deciding the tradeoff here will be easy.